# How can I run the same jQuery function on several different ids?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a gallery where clicking each image opens an isolated lightbox where you can click through related images, but must stay within the set. I have got it so that it can dynamically add images to the slideshow, but I am having trouble getting it to create several separated slideshows rather than one continuous one

I've made a simple codepen to illustrate what I mean - the goal is to have the "next" button cycle through "one" "two" and"three" but then loop back to "one" (rather than continue to "four") and have similar behavior in "four" through "six"

As you can see, it works, but all the images ("One" through "Six") are in one long slideshow. I was hoping that the "Starts with" selector would do it for me, but it still seems to grab all of them.

Codepen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbBWOj

CSS:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; background: #efefef; text-align:center; font-size:30px;}
ul
{list-style-type: none;}
/* lightbox styles */
#lightbox { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background:
  url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA9JREFUeNpiYGBg2AwQYAAAuAC01qHx9QAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==) repeat; }

#lightbox p { text-align: right; color: #fff; margin-right: 20px; font-size: 12px; }

#lightbox img { max-width: 940px; }

/* slideshow styles */
#slideshow { position: relative; z-index: 100; width: 600px; height: 350px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px; background-color: #fff; box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); }
#slideshow ul > li { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; right: 10px; bottom: 10px; list-style: none; }
.nav { display: none; }
.prev, .next { position: absolute; top: 50%; background: rgba(100, 100, 100, .5); padding: .25em .5em; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; }
.next { right: 10px; }
.prev { left: 10px; }
```

HTML:

```
    <ul class="imageSet" id="set1">
        <li>
            <a href="http://placehold.it/600x350/f99/fff&text=one" class="lightboxTrigger">
            one
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://placehold.it/600x350/9f9/fff&text=two" class="lightboxTrigger">
            two
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://placehold.it/600x350/99f/fff&text=three" class="lightboxTrigger">
            three
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

  <ul class="imageSet" id="set2">
        <li>
            <a href="http://placehold.it/600x350/f99/fff&text=four" class="lightboxTrigger">
            four
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://placehold.it/600x350/9f9/fff&text=five" class="lightboxTrigger">
            five
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://placehold.it/600x350/99f/fff&text=six" class="lightboxTrigger">
            six
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // global variables for script
  var current, size;

  $('.lightboxTrigger').click(function(e) {

    // prevent default click event
    e.preventDefault();

    // grab href from clicked element
    var image_href = $(this).attr("href");  

    // determine the index of clicked trigger
    var slideNum = $('.lightboxTrigger').index(this);

    // find out if #lightbox exists
    if ($('#lightbox').length > 0) {        
      // #lightbox exists
      $('#lightbox').fadeIn(300);
      // #lightbox does not exist - create and insert (runs 1st time only)
    } else {                                
      // create HTML markup for lightbox window
      var lightbox =
          '<div id="lightbox">' +
          '<p>Click to close</p>' +
          '<div id="slideshow">' +
          '<ul></ul>' +        
          '<div class="nav">' +
          '<a href="#prev" class="prev slide-nav">prev</a>' +
          '<a href="#next" class="next slide-nav">next</a>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>';

      //insert lightbox HTML into page
      $('body').append(lightbox);

      // fill lightbox with .lightboxTrigger hrefs in #imageSet
      $("[id^='set']").find('.lightboxTrigger').each(function() {
        var $href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#slideshow ul').append(
          '<li>' +
          '<img src="' + $href + '">' +
          '</li>'
        );
      });

    }

    // setting size based on number of objects in slideshow
    size = $('#slideshow ul > li').length;

    // hide all slide, then show the selected slide
    $('#slideshow ul > li').hide();
    $('#slideshow ul > li:eq(' + slideNum + ')').show();

    // set current to selected slide
    current = slideNum;
  });

  //Click anywhere on the page to get rid of lightbox window
  $('body').on('click', '#lightbox', function() { // using .on() instead of .live(). more modern, and fixes event bubbling issues
    $('#lightbox').fadeOut(300);
  });

  // show/hide navigation when hovering over #slideshow
  $('body').on(
    { mouseenter: function() {
      $('.nav').fadeIn(300);
    }, mouseleave: function() {
      $('.nav').fadeOut(300);
    }
    },'#slideshow');

  // navigation prev/next
  $('body').on('click', '.slide-nav', function(e) {

    // prevent default click event, and prevent event bubbling to prevent lightbox from closing
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var $this = $(this);
    var dest;

    // looking for .prev
    if ($this.hasClass('prev')) {
      dest = current - 1;
      if (dest < 0) {
        dest = size - 1;
      }
    } else {
      // in absence of .prev, assume .next
      dest = current + 1;
      if (dest > size - 1) {
        dest = 0;
      }
    }

    // fadeOut curent slide, FadeIn next/prev slide
    $('#slideshow ul > li:eq(' + current + ')').fadeOut(750);
    $('#slideshow ul > li:eq(' + dest + ')').fadeIn(750);

    // update current slide
    current = dest;
  });

});
```

Comment: Why not _$(".imageSet")_ instead of ids?

Comment: Tried that - unfortunately using a class has the same issue (since both sets would be the same class). I was hoping that using ids would be a way around it but no joy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the selector to get only the ones under that ul using the id something like this

```
$("[id^='"+$(this).parent().parent()[0].id+"']")
```

edit: -

this would fix the start point for the index,

```
var slideNum = $("[id^='"+$(this).parent().parent()[0].id+"']").find('.lightboxTrigger').index(this);
```

I also added the delete thing for the lightbox

check the code again

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEVmWz

Comment: This is close! It seems to work for the first set you click, but if you then try to switch sets, the second set is empty. I guess we need to reset the content on exiting the lightbox?

Answer (score 0):

You have the HTML already useable.  Embed your code inside a layer selecting the .imageSet elements

```
$('.imageSet').each(function(imageSetIndex, imageSetElement){
    ...
});
```

Then use the imageSetElement as the context to your .lightboxTrigger selector

```
$('.imageSet').each(function(imageSetIndex, imageSetElement){

    $('.lightboxTrigger', imageSetElement).click(function(e) {
        ... 
    });

});
```

Finally, make a change to handle the $('#slideshow ul') LI elements to use just the .lightboxTrigger elements in scope.